# How can I export only my notes from the Notes app and import to another Mac?

Tags: macos, mac, high-sierra, notes.app, import

Rather than set up iCloud sync, I’d like to export / import notes.

Is there a way to export all my notes written in the Notes app in any format so that I can import them to another Mac?

Comment: Ok, you might want to [edit] your question with that restriction because you did indicate "any format".

Comment: Notes can import TXT, RTF, RTFD, HTML and Evernote XML Export (ENEX), so any of these formats is fine.

Comment: I’ve made this explicitly about export/import. Clearly iCloud sync is the easiest way to do this. Once sync up, one sync down, then disable the sync. Let’s assume Jim has a good reason to not just sync

Answer (score 2):

1. > Is there an option to save notes to iCloud?

   Yes, in system preferences-> iCloud.
2. > It seems I cannot import a pdf to notes.

   You can. The regular method of File-> import->import file, won't work. You can drag and drop multiple files into a note.
3. > Scripting.

   That would be a task for AppleScript.
4. > How to import the notes to new Mac?

   If the same Apple ID is used on both Macs, turn on the iCloud for notes (see 1^). They'll sync. If different IDs are used, there is no easy method. You can add collaborators (or people) and send them the invite. Then they can import all the notes to their Mac.

Comment: You are right. I could drag and drop the exported as PDF back to a note but it is not editable anymore. It is a PDF inside a note.

Comment: With the option (1) for iCloud, does that save everything in Mac or only Notes?

Comment: I don’t know the defaults but you get a choice in saving particular documents in the “iCloud drive” tab in the finder. Also, photos, calendar, reminders, safari are there for backup. It's up to you to turn on iCloud sync for certain things.

Comment: Scripting would be a task for AppleScript. There are no Automator actions for Notes.

Comment: @benwiggy As I said, yet to learn. I don't want to update it as it pushes other good questions off the homepage. https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3584/why-was-my-edit-rejected?cb=1

Comment: The meta post is about minimal edits on old posts, not quality improvements on recent posts. You **should** update if you see a way to significantly improve your own answers (or those of others).

Comment: @nohillside This was an old post until Mark improved the grammar, which he stumbled upon after rejecting one of my edit requests.

Comment: Substantial edits on old posts are fine as well :-) And actually, most edits are. The linked meta post addresses a very specific pattern of applying a non-substantial edit to a very old post while missing the substantial parts.

Answer (score 2):

There is an app on the app store named [Note2Txt](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/note2txt/id1103045981?mt=12) that will convert each note to a text file and save it to a directory/folder of your choice. The app is $0.99 and is extremely fast and efficient. I back up my notes using this app. Each text file is given the name of the note with extension .txt

Comment: Hi - I’ve edited the question significantly. This really seems to be a round trip - expert / import as opposed to a backup of the whole data set in the user folder. Wanted to give you a heads up the question is edited now a bit.

Comment: As to your answer, +1 - you didn’t say that notes can import these - you might call that out explicitly - once these are exported, you can draw the folder into Notes and import them all or you have do drag them one by one, etc...